# Windows 10 shows recent items when right-clicking in the taskbar, but then says it can't find them

Tags: taskbar, microsoft-word-2013, jumplist

For months and months now, I have been unable to reopen recently-opened filed from MS Word via the taskbar.  I can **see** the files there when I right-click them, but every time I try to click on the file, it says:

> The item you selected is unavailable.  It might have have been moved, renamed, or removed. Do you want to remove it from the list?

It's annoying & very frustrating, because I can **literally** close out a file, & before doing *anything* else go back & right-click, & it will give me that message.  Even worse, I ***can*** do this with MS Excel files, as well as recent folders from File Explorer or recent pages loaded in Chrome.  But if I open MS Word, & go to "Recent Documents", I can open ***every single file***.  I can also open them from Recent Files in File Explorer, or if I go to the Start Menu and right-click on the Word icon there.  It's **only** from the Taskbar itself that it's not working, & **only** with MS Word.

I'm completely patched, I'm running Office Professional Plus (2013), and I've even disabled & reenabled the option to see recent documents (from Settings --> Personalization --> Start --> Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar and in File Explorer Quick Access).

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC (initial Windows repairs).   .......   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Was unable to run the "/Online/Cleaup-image/Restorehealth" option, it said that option is "unknown", with "error: 87".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. You have some damage to your machine / operating system.

You need to run a Windows 10 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

**(1) Keep Everything**: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.  Let us hope this option works.

**(2) Keep Data:** Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost. Note that this will not repair a damaged User Profile.

**(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else** and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

My guess at this point is that the User Profile is damaged and as noted you cannot repair a bad profile.